# Using Angular UI-Router in Chrome App (not extension)

Tags: google-chrome-app

I am trying to use Chrome App, which will be a typical angular single page app, with multiple partial views etc. I am using https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router for the views/routing purpose.

After sandboxing the html page hosting angular and all other scripts, I am getting this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome-extension://hjilagjleifhpbceplnonicobelbcibo/html/partials/waiting.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Here "waiting.html" is a partial view I want to inject in main view. 
Anyway to get around this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [local xmlhttprequest from sandboxed page in chrome packaged app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20816855/local-xmlhttprequest-from-sandboxed-page-in-chrome-packaged-app)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251420/couldnt-load-template-using-templateurl-in-angularjs